# php-apcu (CGI/FastCGI) apc_fetch always return false

Tags: php, apache, apc

When using the php-apcu (https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu) extension (not apc) in a php CGI environment the stored data from`apc_store` are empty.

Anyone has experiences on how to solve this issue?

**Example PHP File:** test-apc.php

```
<?php
$k = 'test';
if(isset($_GET['get'])) {
    $result = apc_fetch($k);
    echo "Read entry '$k': $result";
} else if(isset($_GET['clear'])) {
    echo "Clear entry '$k'";
    apc_clear_cache('user');
} else {
    apc_store($k, "HelloWord");
    echo "Write entry '$k' set";
}
print_r(apc_cache_info('user'));
?>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open `http://server/test-apc.php` to call `apc_store`
2. Open `http://server/test-apc.php?get` to receive stored data using `apc_fetch`

BTW: *apc_cache_info('user') shows it properly with first request, second is empty*

**Relevant packages (OS: Debian 3.2.63):**

- Apache 2.2.22 (mpm-prefork, suexec-custom, wrapper)
- php5.5 as CGI
- php5-apcu 4.0.7
- (and dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module php-apcu is not fully compatible with CGI/fcgid.

**Possible reason:** CGI/fcgid executes the php interpreter as a **new instance** on every HTTP REQUEST. So apcu/apc cannot recover the user caches.

The module **mod-fastcgi** (*non-free package for Debian*) together with **php5-fpm** can provide remedy.
Its uses a different technique to manage processes.

---

http://php-fpm.org/wiki/ (down atm - 2015-09-02)