# Session is always empty

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, pixel

I am using a tracking pixel in my project, firing this pixel will make a request to the server which will run a PHP script. At the PHP script I need to store a value to be always available for that script and for every call, So I am trying to use session but it seems like always **NOT-Set**!

```
session_start();
require_once("../../abc.php");

// Allow requests from different domains
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if(isset($_SESSION['log_file']) && !empty($_SESSION['log_file'])) {

    //Never goes here

} else {

    //Always goes here
}
```

Any Idea why the session is always Not-set?
and what is the best session's alternative in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: WHere did you set the session values for `log_file`? Try a `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Where does the `$_SESSION['log_file']` came from? Or are you even providing it?

Comment: in the **else block**,
`else {
 $_SESSION['log_file'] = $log_file;
}`
it must go there in the first run only.
I tried to run the script using a browser and it works fine, but when the pixel makes the request it always goes to the else and set a new value for the session instead of using the one that initialized in first request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that **Empty session created on every http request**.
Also apc(u) facing the same problem. see the links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php#79321

[php-apcu (CGI/FastCGI) apc_fetch always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270449/php-apcu-cgi-fastcgi-apc-fetch-always-return-false)